# How to pass array as parameter through url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, associative-array

I have simple html code where I want to pass two arrays through url.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/account/print_bs/$data/$data1";?>" target="_blank">PRINT</a>
```

Where $data and $data1 are two associative arrays. But it gives me error  array to string conversion..So how do I do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just append an array to the url. What you could do is to save them in the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and then you have access to them on the next site like this:

site1:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["array1"] = $data;
    $_SESSION["array2"] = $data1;

?>
```

site2:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    print_r($_SESSION["array1"]);
    print_r($_SESSION["array2"]);

?>
```

Comment: thnks for reply..but Is there any other way of doing it??

Comment: @KedarB I think that's the best way to do this. All other ways would just be more complicated

Comment: @KedarB And on the second site just do: `$data = $_SESSION["array1"]; $data1 = $_SESSION["array2"];` And you have the arrays back in the same variable names